# Problems with JWT Authentication after moving from ASP.NET Core 6.0 to 7.0 (AuthenticationConfigurationProviderExtensions)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

We started to move our Application from ASP.NET Core 6.0 to 7.0. This application was running fine, with a basic JWT authentication schema.

After the updates, we started to receive this Exception:

Caller:
builder.Authentication.AddJwtBearer();

**Exception**:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationConfigurationProviderExtensions'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearerConfigureOptions.Configure(string
> name, JwtBearerOptions options)
>
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string
> name)

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` version 7.0?

Comment: @OkanKaradag, yes! 7.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is a compatibility problem between simultaneous .NET 7 versions (Preview and Release) installed on the machine. In my case, I had .NET `7.0.100-preview.5.22307.18` and `7.0.100` installed.

Even using the 7.0.0 package versions on the .csprojects, I faced this issue.

After experiencing this problem, I just uninstalled the .NET `7.0.100-preview.5.22307.18` from my local machine, and updated my Visual Studio 2022 to the `17.4` version.

Running these steps, all these problems have been successfully resolved.

Resumed steps:

1. Uninstall old preview versions from your machine:
   Version: `.NET 7.0.100-preview.5.22307.18`
2. Check if you are running the latest version of .NET 7. Today (November, 2022) our latest available version is `7.0.100`.

Check if your package versions are pointing to this new release:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
```

All done.